# How to name variables on the fly?

Tags: r, assign, r-faq

Is it possible to create new variable names on the fly?

I'd like to read data frames from a list into new variables with numbers at the end. Something like orca1, orca2, orca3...

If I try something like

```
paste("orca",i,sep="")=list_name[[i]]
```

I get this error

```
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Is there another way around this?

Comment: As long as we're giving out r-faq tags let's give the link (FAQ 7.21: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f )

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Use `assign`:

```
assign(paste("orca", i, sep = ""), list_name[[i]])
```

Comment: This is how to do this.  There's a meta-question here which is, "Should I do this?"  The answer is almost always "no".  Named elements in a list are almost always preferred.

Comment: The answer is almost always "no" except when it isn't.

Comment: Well of course.  But most people seeking this answer aren't doing so from a position of having rejected a list for their application.

Comment: @Ari B. Friedman I generate variable names for datasets I save in mypackage/data. Each one in its file with same name for the file and the data in it (given R recommendations for data in package). Each dataset is about 10M and the total is ~ 17Go I hardly see an other way.

Comment: What if my new variable is a column name and I want to name it on the fly like XYZ$assign... I guess I can not use it like this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't use `paste0`?

Comment: This is a bad solution.

Answer (score 37):

It seems to me that you might be better off with a list rather than using `orca1`, `orca2`, etc, ... then it would be `orca[1]`, `orca[2]`, ...

Usually you're making a list of variables differentiated by nothing but a number because that number would be a convenient way to access them later.

```
orca <- list()
orca[1] <- "Hi"
orca[2] <- 59
```

Otherwise, `assign` is just what you want.

Comment: I agree. Usually when people think they want to name variables on the fly, what they really want is a different data structure.

Comment: +1 (FAQ 7.21: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f ) discusses this nicely

Answer (score 11):

Don't make data frames. Keep the list, name its elements but do not attach it.

The biggest reason for this is that if you make variables on the go, almost always you will later on have to iterate through each one of them to perform something useful. There you will again be forced to iterate through each one of the names that you have created on the fly.

It is far easier to name the elements of the list and iterate through the names.

As far as attach is concerned, its really bad programming practice in R and can lead to a lot of trouble if you are not careful.

Comment: So, do an attach, but only after having done the iteration through the list?

Answer (score 5):

[FAQ says:](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f)

If you have

```
varname <- c("a", "b", "d")
```

you can do

```
get(varname[1]) + 2
```

for

```
a + 2
```

or

```
assign(varname[1], 2 + 2)
```

for

```
a <- 2 + 2
```

So it looks like you use GET when you want to evaluate a formula that uses a variable (such as a concatenate), and ASSIGN when you want to assign a value to a pre-declared variable.

**Syntax for assign:** 
assign(x, value)

**x:** a variable name, given as a character string. No coercion is done, and the first element of a character vector of length greater than one will be used, with a warning.

**value:** value to be assigned to x.

Answer (score 0):

Another tricky solution is to name elements of list and `attach` it:

```
list_name = list(
    head(iris),
    head(swiss),
    head(airquality)
    )

names(list_name) <- paste("orca", seq_along(list_name), sep="")
attach(list_name)

orca1
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: tricky, but not wise. if the answer is `attach` you're usually asking the wrong question ...

Answer (score 0):

And this option?

```
list_name<-list()
for(i in 1:100){
    paste("orca",i,sep="")->list_name[[i]]
}
```

It works perfectly. In the example you put,  first line is missing, and then gives you the error message.

Comment: This doesn't address OP's question. We have a list with dataframes, and we want to assign it to dataframes, named as orca1, orca2, etc.

Comment: "List with dataframes" = "list OF dataframes"?