# R: new variable in the for loop

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to name variables on the fly in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679193/how-to-name-variables-on-the-fly-in-r)

Ok this is very basic but I cannot work it out...
In the for loop I would like to create new variable with varying name:

```
for (i in 1:4)  
a$i=i
```

So my new variables: `a1,a2,a3,a4` would have value `1,2,3,4` respectively.
Is there easy and fast way to do this in R?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f

Comment: Try `a[i] <- i` (and the recommended reading above).

Comment: thanks Joshua and Ben for links - it solved my problem!