# Variable in R loop as results of the function

Tags: r, loops

I have a problem processing filename as variable in a loop in R

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.tab",full.name=T)
for (a in files) { aname <- strsplit(basename(a), "\\.")[[1]][1]
                   aname <- read.table(a,header=TRUE, sep="\t",comment.char="")
                }
```

It produces only one object: `aname`, if I use following:

```
for (a in files) { c(strsplit(basename(a), "\\.")[[1]][1]) <- read.table(a,header=TRUE,
                        sep="\t",comment.char="")
                }
```

it produces: could not find function "c<-". But if I do

```
for (a in files) { aname <- strsplit(basename(a), "\\.")[[1]][1]
                   print(aname)
                }
```

The output is a list of files without extension, as expected. So, the question is: how do I make result of a function a variable name?
Thank you!

Comment: Assigning variable names on the fly has been discussed repeatedly on [so]. Try this for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2679193/429846

Comment: Pardone my ignorance, but assign(strsplit(basename(a), "\\.")[[1]][1], read.table(a,header=TRUE, sep="\t",comment.char="")) doesnt work...Update: I solved it already. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not in processing the file name but in the way you've written the loop. Essentially you are doing:

```
for(i in list.of.files) {
  foo <- processName(i)
  foo <- read.table(foo)
}
```

when viewed like that, it is clear that `foo` gets written to twice for each iteration of the loop and hence can only ever take the value of the last `read.table()` call.

What you want to do is allocate storage for the list of files before you enter the loop, and then fill in that list as you go. For example:

```
aname <- vector("list", length = length(files))
fnames <- character(length(files))
for(i in seq_along(aname)) {
  fnames[i] <- strsplit(basename(files[i]), "\\.")[[1]][1]
  aname[i] <- read.table(a, header=TRUE, sep="\t", comment.char="")
}
names(aname) <- fnames
```

Having the objects contained in a list is a useful feature so you don;t have all those objects banging around. As they are contained within a list you can operate on each object using `lapply()` or similar.

If you really want to have an individual object that is has the filename without extension as its name for all files, then you could use `assign()`, but I don't recommend it

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.tab", full.name=TRUE)
for (a in files) {
  aname <- strsplit(basename(a), "\\.")[[1]][1]
  assign(aname, read.table(a, header=TRUE, sep="\t", comment.char="")
}
```

See `?assign` for more.

Comment: Thank you very much! for (a in files) {
  aname <- strsplit(basename(a), "\\.")[[1]][1]
  assign(aname, read.table(a, header=TRUE, sep="\t", comment.char=""))
} --- work perfectly, I didn't know assign function.