# Change variable name in for loop using R

Tags: r

I have a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:10){ Ai=d+rnorm(3)}
```

What I would like to do is have `A1, A2,A3...A10` and I have the variable `i` in the variable name.

It doesn't work this way, but I'm probably missing some small thing. How can I use the `i` in the for loop to assign different variable names?

Comment: for (i in 1:10) { A[i] = d + rnorm(3)} should work.

Comment: that doesn't work if the variable doesn't exist yet

Comment: In that case, you have to use `assign`: `for (i in 1:10){ assign(paste("A",i, sep=""), (d + rnorm(3))) }`

Comment: doesn't work, I tried this exact code

Comment: Sidenote: To *access* variables in a loop, use `get`: `for (i in 1:10) { print(get(paste("A", i, sep=""))) }`

Comment: Welcome to cross validated (and stackexchange), @ghb. Your question is rather about programming than about statistics. Such questions are more suited for stackexchange, so I voted to move the question over here.

Comment: @COOLSerdash and what if I want to access the 'i'th element of that variable in a loop? so basically Ai[i]

Answer (score 121):

```
d <- 5
for(i in 1:10) { 
 nam <- paste("A", i, sep = "")
 assign(nam, rnorm(3)+d)
}
```

More info [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assign.html) or even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679193/how-to-name-variables-on-the-fly-in-r)!

Comment: thanks this works perfectly, I have a 'next step' question: what if I use this method in a loop and then I would like to use the 'i'th element of the created vector so basically Ai is A1 in the first iteration but I want to access Ai[i]

Comment: @ghb: then it is definitively time to go for a matrix (`A [i, i]`) or a list (`A [[i]][i]`) - much easier than `get (paste0 ("x", i))[i]`. Plus you can easily assign new values for the matrix and list versions, but for the `get`/`assign` version you'd need a temporary variable.

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(236)`: *The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand why you should never use the assign
function.
   -- Greg Snow
      R-help (July 2009)*

Comment: Why it creates also `i` and `nam` variables?

Comment: Could I suggest adding `rm(nam)` at the end just for cleanup?
You're a legend, thanks. This works exactly as hoped :)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.
`> ls()
 [1] "A1"  "A10" "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"`
But how do I get "A01", "A02" etc.?

Comment: If you are new to R, consider [using a `list` or `matrix`, as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16566800/1048186). For most purposes, they will do what you need.

Comment: It's an old question, but to do what @Gecko asked, you can use sprintf:
`sprintf("A%02i", i)`
This will write a two digit number with a leading 0 for values under 10.
Also works with %03i etc

Answer (score 18):

You could use `assign`, but using `assign` (or `get`) is often a symptom of a programming structure that is not very R like. Typically, lists or matrices allow cleaner solutions.

- with a list:

  ```
  A <- lapply (1 : 10, function (x) d + rnorm (3))
  ```
- with a matrix:

  ```
  A <- matrix (rep (d, each = 10) + rnorm (30), nrow = 10)
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is using eval and parse, as in

```
d = 5
for (i in 1:10){
     eval(parse(text = paste('a', 1:10, ' = d + rnorm(3)', sep='')[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```r
  for (i in 1:10) {
    assign(as.vector(paste0('A', i)), rnorm(3))
  }
```