# changing part of the name of an R object within a for loop

Tags: r, object, names

I am trying to repeat the same process multiple times across multiple data sources and rather than write out each process I want to use a for loop but I am having trouble changing the names of the data source and output object.

In an example I have three data sources called `sim1_1`, `sim1_2` and `sim1_3` and I want to do a calculation on each one to produce output `supp1_1`, `supp1_2` and `supp1_3`.  So I have two vectors of the names of the data sources and the output I want to create.

```
data <- c("sim1_1", "sim1_2", "sim1_3")             
supp <- c("supp1_1", "supp1_2", "supp1_3")
```

so rather than write:

```
supp1_1 <- sim1_1$epi$tx.full.supp/sim1_1$epi$diag
supp1_2 <- sim1_2$epi$tx.full.supp/sim1_2$epi$diag
```

etc..

I want to use a loop where `supp[i]` and `data[i]` are defined by the location `i` on the vectors I defined above.  I can define the text I want from the vectors but the text isn't applied in the object name.  See the example below.

```
data[i]
# [1] "sim1_1"
head(sim1_1$epi$tx.full.supp[1])
#   sim1
# 1    0
# 2    0
# 3    0
# 4    0
# 5    0
# 6    0

head(data[i]$epi$tx.full.supp[1])
# Error in data[i]$epi : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: Can you please make a minimally reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/2201/for-loops#t=201607221834422385096

Comment: This has been answered many times before. You can just `paste` a name into `assign`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change variable name in for loop using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566799/change-variable-name-in-for-loop-using-r)