# Auto increment of variable name

Tags: r

I am using R to create a variable which can increment after certain operations.
i.e., I have a variable called node and I want to write a function to increment it like node1, node2, node3..etc., each time the function is called.

Is this possible?
Please help

Comment: You might have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is it possible to step back and give a wider explanation? There might be a better route than writing functions that affect environmental variables.

Comment: Have you tried using the <<- operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change variable name in for loop using R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566799/change-variable-name-in-for-loop-using-r)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list in your case `node <- list()`. You can now use the increment to save the your value to the "position" in the list like `node[[i]] <- 'my value'`. Just increment `i` like you wanted to do with the variable name. Access the value by `node[[1]]` etc.