# advantage of list over numbered data.tables

Tags: r, list, assign

I have two nested for-loops, within each of which I load (here simulate) and manipulate data, to create several lists.

```
library(data.table)
for(i in 1:20){
    perm <- rnorm(1); res <- list()
    for(j in 1:500){
        temp <- runif(5,0,20)
        res[[j]] <- data.table(a=temp/perm, b=temp+perm)
    }
    assign(paste0("x",i),res); rm(res)
}
```

Because the inner for-loop outputs a data.table, I create at each iteration of the outer for-loop a list to hold the different data.tables produced by the inner loop.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16566800/5089467) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16566800/5089467) that the setup using `assign(.)` is not very Rly and I wonder whether this can be improved.

On the one hand, I like that the lists of the j-loops are numbered so I can relate them back to the datasets loaded there (here simulated). On the other hand, the i-loop could produce a list of lists but I wonder what the advantage would be besides scalability.

Comment: Instead of creating objects in the global env, store it in a list and do the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would do you much good to use either the base R `*pply*` family of functions, or the `map_*` family from `purrr`. Here is your code using base R:

```
res <- lapply(1:20, function(i) {
  perm <- rnorm(100)
  ret <- lapply(1:500, function(j) {
         temp <- runif(5, 0, 20)
         data.frame(a=temp/perm[i], b=temp+perm[i])
      })
})
```

Advantages: no need to populate the current environment, you have one object (`res`) which you can easily manipulate with loops and more. The most immediate advantage of storing the results in a list is *convenience*. You can save all results in one go (`save(res, file="res.rda")`), count how many you have (`length(res)`), go through them with `lapply` or `map`.

Say, you want to get the first `j` index from each of the 20 replicates:

```
j1 <- map(res, ~ .[[1]])
```

Oh, you wanted it all in a single data frame?

```
j1 <- map_dfr(res, ~ .[[1]])
```

Second advantage: you immediately see that your code is broken. For each i, you generate 100 random numbers (`perm`), but you only ever use... one of them for each `i`! (`perm[i]`, for i in 1..20). Why do you need 100 of them at all?

Comment: 2: Absolutely — like I said, in fact I load data and this was meant to be an example. I fixed it. From what I can see, this is also faster. Another advantage?

Comment: What's the disadvantage of "populating the current environment" if I delete the intermediate objects?

Comment: Try to answer the question: what is the advantage of having a directory structure when I can put everything on my desktop? ;-) Basically, the main disadvantage is that you have to delete the intermediate objects, you have to keep track of them, and if something goes wrong your environment gets messy.

Comment: a propos "Another advantage": "All right, but apart from the sanitation, the medicine, education, wine, public order, irrigation, roads, a fresh water system, and public health, what have the Romans ever done for us?"

Comment: I meant to ask whether speed was another general advantage. Thanks for the patient explanation of all the rest.

Answer (score 3):

A list of lists is great and easy to work with. However, a matrix of mode "list" can be a very convenient alternative:

```
m <- 2
n <- 3
res <- vector(length = m * n, mode = "list")
res <- matrix(res, ncol = m)

library(data.table)
for(i in 1:n){
  perm <- rnorm(100)
  for(j in 1:m){
    temp <- runif(5,0,20)
    res[i,j] <- list(data.table(a=temp/perm[i], b=temp+perm[i]))
  }
}

res[1,] #result from first iteration of outer loop
#[[1]]
#            a         b
#1:  -6.434118  7.744621
#2:  -7.741497  9.607878
#3:  -3.200882  3.136663
#4:  -8.283567 10.380427
#5: -10.989466 14.236833
#
#[[2]]
#            a         b
#1: -12.045692 15.742150
#2: -13.199384 17.386375
#3:  -6.176316  7.377206
#4: -13.549293 17.885059
#5:  -3.025583  2.886829
```

Comment: What is the advantage of a "listified matrix" over a regular list?

Comment: @bumblebee that you can easily access an element by `i` and `j` simultaneously. For example, you might be optimizing two parameters.

Comment: The advantage is matrix subsetting. If you want to get the result from the first iteration of the inner loop for each iteration of the outer loop, you would need to loop with a nested list. Much more convenient with a matrix.