# Hide data in global environment

Tags: r

Is there a function that allows for data to be hidden in the global environment but it can still be accessed?

For example, I have a very long script with up to 100+ lines and my global environment is looking messy, there is too much and it strains my brain finding what is necessary.

I have searched up similar questions and they involve creating a package, quite frankly I have no time to learn, at this moment.

Comment: You may want to look into preventing the predicament you are in. Here is a link where the selected answer is bad practice - the second answer is better for R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566799/change-variable-name-in-for-loop-using-r

Answer (score 8):

If you name all the objects you don't want to appear in the global environment starting with a dot (`.`), for example:
`.foo <- 'bar'` the object will be accesible but will be hidden in the global environment or in any `ls()` call:

```
> .foo <- 'bar'
> .foo
[1] "bar"
> ls()
character(0)
>
```

Edit: Adding a working example

Comment: But, even if this works, and is what you asked, I would take a look at the @Roman Luštrik answer, as it will pay off on the long run if you plan using R heavily.

Comment: This answer also addresses the situation where RStudio displays all variables in its environment pane and you may have one you don't want displayed (for example a non-critical password used in a script). Just preface the password with `.`

Answer (score 2):

Possible solutions would be:

1. removing objects once they're not needed any more
2. put related variables into a list (hello `lapply`, `sapply`)
3. move into a separate custom environment (`new.env()`)
4. simplify the script to not use as many objects
5. run script in batch mode and miss out on what the environment looks like altogether

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an XY problem, 100 lines is quite small, it's likely that you are using too many temporary variables or are numbering objects that should be in a list.

You also don't mention why you don't like your environment to be "messy", my guess is that maybe you don't like the output of `ls()` ?

Then maybe you'll be happy to learn about the `pattern` argument of `ls()` which will allow you to filter the result, mostly useful with prefixes or suffixes as in the following examples :

```r
something <- 1
some_var <- 2
another_var <- 3
ls(pattern ="^some")
#> [1] "some_var"  "something"
ls(pattern="var$")
#> [1] "another_var" "some_var"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>