# For Loop across several data frames or tibbles

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse, tibble

I have 5 tibbles for successive years 2016 to 2020. I am doing the same thing to each of the sets of tibbles so I want to use a for-loop rather than copying and pasting the same code 5 times. I have named the tibbles in the following way with the final number indicating the year of the data:

- alpha_20
- beta_20
- gamma_20
- delta_20
- epsilon_20

My thought was to do this:

```
for (i in 16:20) {
    alpha_a_[i]<-alpha_[i]%>%
    mutate(NEWVAR=1+OLDVAR)%>%
    select(NEWVAR, VAR2, VAR3)
    
    beta_a_[i]<-beta_[i]%>%
    group_by(PIN)%>%
    summarize(sum(VAR1))
    
    # and so on for all 5 tibbles
    
    }
```

But I think I am not calling the tibble correctly because the code breaks at the first mutate. I can't seem to figure out how to instruct it to take the tibbles ending in "16" and then the tibbles ending in "17" and so on.

Comment: Hi Knesse. Welcome to SO! Your question contains code, but it is difficult to help you without some test data so we can run your code and examine where/why it fails. Here is a link on how to make a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you! As you say, I am new to posting here. The feedback is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things going on here. First, in order to actually call the name of your tibble, you're going to want use the `get()` function on the string name. Try typing "alpha_20" vs. get("alpha_20") in the command line. However, the way you have it coded now as `alpha_[i]` won't generate the string you want. To generate the name of your tibble as a string, you're going to need to do something like `get(paste0("alpha_", i))`.

That's all just to get the tibble you want. To edit/save it within the for loop, look into the `assign()` command (see [Change variable name in for loop using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566799/change-variable-name-in-for-loop-using-r)). So all in all, your code will look something like this:

```
>   require(tidyverse)
>   alpha_20 <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
>   alpha_20
  x  y
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10
>   
>   for (i in 20) {
+     assign(paste0('alpha_', i), 
+            get(paste0('alpha_', i)) %>% 
+              mutate(z = 11:15))
+   }
>   alpha_20
  x  y  z
1 1  6 11
2 2  7 12
3 3  8 13
4 4  9 14
5 5 10 15
```

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for the reference too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of `get`, `assign` and `paste`.

```
for (i in 16:20) {
  alpha <- get(paste("alpha_", i, sep = "")) %>%
    mutate(NEWVAR = 1 + OLDVAR) %>%
    select(NEWVAR, VAR2, VAR3)
  assign(paste("alpha_a_", i, sep = ""), alpha)
  
  
  beta <- get(paste("beta_", i, sep = "")) %>%
    group_by(PIN) %>%
    summarize(sum(VAR1))
  assign(paste("beta_a_", i, sep = ""), beta)
  
  # and so on for all 5 tibbles
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. I knew I must just be calling it incorrectly.