# Creating a vector of graph objects in r

Tags: r, igraph

I am currently working with the 'igraph' package on R.

I have created two functions that create a statistical table of graph object that work pretty well if used directly on a single graph object (here is an example of what they look like) :

```
Sfn <- function(x) # Give a table of statistics for nodes

{

Name <- deparse(substitute(x))
Nodes <- V(x)$name
Dtotal <- degree(x, mode="all")
Eigenvector <- eigen_centrality(x)

statistics_table <- data.frame(Nodes,
                               Dtotal,
                               Eigenvector)

colnames(statistics_table) <- c("Nodes","Total Degrees",
                                "Eigenvector centrality")    
write.table(statistics_table, 
            file = paste0("Table_of_",Name,"_nodes.csv"),
            sep=",",
            row.names = F)

print("Success.")

}
```

As I am using several graph objects, I would like not to have to write one line per command, such as :

```
Sfn(g)
Sfn(g2)
Sfn(g3)
# etc...
Sfn(n)
```

I would thus like to create a vector of lists in which I could collect all my graph objects. I created something like that :

```
G <- c(
     list(CC1),list(CC2),list(CC3),
     list(CC4),list(CC5),list(CC6),
     list(CC7),list(CC8),list(CC9),
     list(CC10),list(CC11),list(CC12))
```

Yet, this solution is not optimal. First, it is too long to write if I have, for example, 100 graph objects. Secondly, if I write my script with an `for()` loop, the name of the variable sent to my function will be the name of the parameter of `for()`, thus, ruining the variable `Name` of my function `Sfn`. In other words, the script `for(i in G) {Sfn(G)}` does not work, because the variable `Name` will be equal to `i` :

```
# In my function Sfn, Name <- deparse(substitute(i)), 
for(i in G) {print(deparse(substitute(i)))} 
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
[1] "i"
```

Also, the solution there : ([Change variable name in for loop using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566799/change-variable-name-in-for-loop-using-r)) does not work because I have, in my graph objects, very different randomly attributed graph names (such as "CC1","g2","CT3","CC1T3", etc).

Do you have any idea on how I could possibly:

1 - achieve a better way of creating a vector of graph objects ?

2 - make the name of the parameter sent to my variable the same as the actual name of the variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `deparse(substitute())` makes it hard to do what you want.  If you really want to do this without changing your `Sfn` function, you'll need to construct a call to it as a string and parse that.  For example:

```r
names <- c("CC1", "g2")
Sfn <- function(x) deparse(substitute(x))   # just return the name
result <- list()
for (n in names) {
  result[[n]] <- eval(parse(text = paste("Sfn(", n, ")")))
}
result
#> $CC1
#> [1] "CC1"
#> 
#> $g2
#> [1] "g2"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

This could be much simpler if you passed the name you want as a string to `Sfn`, instead of trying to get it using `deparse(substitute())`, e.g.

```r
names <- c("CC1", "g2")
Sfn <- function(x, name) name
result <- list()
for (n in names)
  result[[n]] <- Sfn(n, n)
result
#> $CC1
#> [1] "CC1"
#> 
#> $g2
#> [1] "g2"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Edited to add:  Not only is the second solution cleaner, it's safer too.  If you don't have complete control of the `names` vector, there's a huge security risk:  someone could set the "name" to some executable code (see https://xkcd.com/327/) and it would be executed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I am not familiar with your formulation however I will try to understand it. I will keep you in touch, but seeing as it seems to work by my side (I have not fully tested it yet), I think it will be of great help.