# Is there a way to use the value of an assigned variable in new variable names in R?

Tags: r, variables

**Goal:** To create a new variable whose name uses the value of a previously assigned variable in R.

**Motivation:** Naming many variables according to some value related to the associated command's property (*e.g.*, an `alpha` value of `0.75` specified for the bar fill on one chart and the point colour on another chart) would make it possible to store many objects with small changes between them on-the-fly without having to change each variable's name every time the value is changed.

Continuing with the example of the `alpha` value given to different plots (above), this should allow us to change the variable value from `0.75` to `0.25`, re-run the plotting commands, and store these plots in variables representatively named for the new opacity being tested.

---

**Simple Example:**

First, a value of `42` is used:

```
number <- 42

var1_number <- rnorm(number)
var2_number <- runif(number)
var3_number <- log(number)
var4_number <- exp(number)
```

Then, the value is changed to `17`:

```
number <- 17

var1_number <- rnorm(number)
var2_number <- runif(number)
var3_number <- log(number)
var4_number <- exp(number)
```

**Desired output:**

The eight variables should be stored in the R environment as:

| Values |  |
| --- | --- |
| `var1_42` | `num [1:42] -0.2298 -0.6823 0.0871 -0.7689 0.1142 . . .` |
| `var1_17` | `num [1:17] 1.241 1.781 1.668 -0.446 -1.668 . . .` |
| `var2_42` | `num [1:42] 0.6926 0.5927 0.7441 0.9804 0.0202 . . .` |
| `var2_17` | `num [1:17] 0.1307 0.3907 0.0599 0.082 0.6091 . . .` |
| `var3_42` | `3.73766961828337` |
| `var3_17` | `2.83321334405622` |
| `var4_42` | `1739274941520500992` |
| `var4_17` | `24154952.7535753` |

**Attempts:**

Using the exact example provided above results in the creation of four variables named explicitly as written: `var1_number`, `var2_number`, `var3_number`, `var4_number`.

Since the variable names are not retrieving an actual value from the defined `number` variable, the names remain the same and the variables are overwritten when the value stored in `number` is changed.

Also, using backticks to indicate a variable does NOT work (*i.e.*, `` var1_`number` <- rnorm(number) ``) as R interprets them as "unexpected symbol"s.

Comment: Yes, a good suggestion. I am aware of this functionality of `knitr` in Rmarkdown. I just wondered if there was a way to do this in a regular R script? Perhaps there is not!

Comment: Yes, the functionality is from base R, that's just one use case in a knitr context.

Comment: I guess the following link has what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566799/change-variable-name-in-for-loop-using-r

Comment: Also a good suggestion, Ignacio. Odd that the link you shared didn't come up during my initial searches - so thanks for adding it here. The only drawback to the 'for' loop with `assign()` method that I can see is the code may become difficult to read with large inputs like complex/multi-line `ggplot()` code chunks. Works well with the example data shared in my question, though!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect lists might be a better choice for keeping these organized.

```
make_list <- function(x) {
  a <- list()
  a$var1 = rnorm(x)
  a$var2 = runif(x)
  a$var3 = log(x)
  a$var4 = exp(x)
  a
}

var17 <- make_list(17)
```

This will help keep the results organized, and will also make it much easier to compute on those results.

```
var17$var1
#[1] -1.30949829  0.51942312 -0.08220472  0.32858289  1.39745159  2.36128781  1.01300924 -1.35826357 -0.98565341  0.80732834
#[11]  0.38359233 -0.37823694  0.51910416  0.81922642  0.62763918  0.70783359  0.02417833
```

This post shares a useful related case where we might save different results in a list to keep them organized and easy to reference:

[tjmahr.com/lists-knitr-secret-weapon](https://tjmahr.com/lists-knitr-secret-weapon)

Comment: This works as an alternative to the desired dynamic variable naming I had in mind! Thanks for the suggestion, Jon.