# How do I assign number to each different model in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm still learning R and I need some advice regarding very simple matter.

```
for (i in 1:6) {
model.i = lm(data1[,i+1] ~ data1[,"mkt"]+data1[,"riskfree"])
print(summary(model(i)))
print(anova(model(i)))
}
```

I want to make six different simple linear regression, and assign different linear regressions to different names; like model.1, model.2, model.3......

But what I wrote there doesn't work as I expected. I would appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: This kind of question has been asked many times before, here is [one good example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2679193/271616). In general, if you think you need to dynamically assign to different variable names, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in a list:

```
lapply((1:6), function(i) lm(data1[,i+1] ~ data1[,"mkt"]+data1[,"riskfree"]))
```

It's much easier.