# How to insert values into variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to take a basename from a file path and insert it into a variable so I can access a column in a dataframe.  I have created some sample data to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

Create some sample data:

```
library(raster)    
## Create a matrix with random data & use image()
xy = matrix(rnorm(400),20,20)
image(xy)

# Turn the matrix into a raster
rast = raster(xy)
# Give it lat/lon coords for 36-37°E, 3-2°S
extent(rast) = c(36,37,-3,-2)
# ... and assign a projection
projection(rast) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
plot(rast)

# Write to disk:
writeRaster(rast, "C:/temp/12345.tif", format = "tif")
```

Create a path to raster

```
path = 'C:/temp/12345.asc
```

Create a raster object:

```
r = raster(file)
```

Sample random locations in raster and report values in a dataframe

```
df = data.frame(sampleRandom(r, size=1000, cells=TRUE, sp=TRUE))
```

Now I need to automate the insertion of the basename into a variable so that it looks like:

```
test = df$X12345
```

---

This is my unsuccessful attempt at inserting the basename into the test variable:

```
require(tools)
name = basename(file_path_sans_ext(path))
test2 = paste('df$', 'X', name, sep = '')

>test2
[1] "df$X12345"
```

This method seems to create a the correct character "df$X12345", although I cannot access the dataframe by calling `test2`.  **How can I construct a series of characters into a functioning variable so that I can access the particular dataframe column?**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2679193/271616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `parse` and `eval`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)
test2 <- "df$b"
eval(parse(text = test2))
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

> test = df[,paste0('X', name)]

Is this what you're looking for?