# Dynamically initializing variables in R using functional programming

Tags: r, functional-programming, lapply

Hi I'm writing a function to read a file and returning a time series. I then need to assign this time series to a variable. I'm trying to do this in a terse way and utilise any functional programming features of R.

```
 # read a file and returns the 
 readFile <- function(  fileName , filePath){
     fullPath <- paste(filePath, filename, sep='');
     f <- as.xts(read.zoo(fullPath, format='%d/%m/%Y', 
                   FUN=as.Date, header=TRUE, sep='\t'));
     return(na.locf(f));
 }

filePath <- 'C://data/'
# real list of files is a lot longer
fnames <- c('d1.csv', 'd2.csv','d3.csv');
varnames <- c('data1', 'data2', 'data3');
```

In the above piece of code I would like to initialise variables by the name of data1, data2, data2 by applying the readfile function to fnames and filepath (which is always constant).

Something like :

```
lapply( fnames, readFile, filePath);
```

The above doesnt work, of course and neither does it do this dynamic variable assignment that I'm trying to achieve. Any R functional programming gurus out there that could guide me ?

The working version of this would look something like :

```
data1 <- readFile(  'd1.csv', filepath);
data2 <- readFile(  'd2.csv', filepath);
```

YIKES

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to name variables on the fly in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679193/how-to-name-variables-on-the-fly-in-r)

Comment: Thanks shadow - yes its partially a duplicate, but I'm also trying to understand how the lapply can be used to achieve this for many variables since I'm new to FP.

Comment: If you really want to do that (read the comments in the linked question: DON'T DO THAT), you could use `mapply(FUN=assign, x=varnames, value=data, MoreArgs=list(envir=.GlobalEnv))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructing many variables with specified names is a somewhat common request on SO and can certainly be managed with the `assign` function, but you'll probably find it easier to handle your data if you build a list instead of multiple variables. For instance, you could read in all the results and obtain a named list with:

```
lst <- setNames(lapply(fnames, readFile, filePath), varnames)
```

Then you could access your results from each csv file with `lst[["data1"]]`, `lst[["data2"]]`, and `lst[["data3"]]`.

The benefit of this approach is that you can now perform an operation over all your time series variables using `lapply(lst, ...)` instead of looping through all your variables or looping through variable names and using the `get` function.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying it now.

Comment: Error in setnames(lapply(fnames, readFile, filePath), varnames) : 
  x is not a data.table or data.frame

Comment: @user1480926 `setNames`, not `setnames`

Comment: Simply brilliant and so so elegant.