# how to access a variable with dynamic name in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created multiple data frames by using below code :

```
assign(paste0("DF_VID", i) , subset(df, df$VID == unique(mydata$VID)[i]))
```

I would like to add new column `class` in each created data frame (`DF_VID1`, `DF_VID2`,...).  I tried `("DF_VID", i)[,"class"] <- 0` 
but it is showing error and when I try with `DF_VID1[, "class"] <- 0` then it runs but just for one data frame.  I want to know how to add new column in each data frame dynamically.

Comment: You might want to consider using a list to store your data frames, if the names only differ by a number, q.v. [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679193/how-to-name-variables-on-the-fly-in-r).

Comment: Also see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) on putting data.frames into lists as well as how to work with them once they are in a list.

Comment: That means indeed you need to work with a list and should consider `allDFlist <- spit(df,df$VID)`

Comment: Thanks to all. @Eric Lecoutre: perfect solution