# How to add a number from a for cycle to the end of each new table?

Tags: tablename

I have a for cycle which makes new table for every i. How can I name those tables ``table_i`?

I have tried to save new tables under the name `table_i`, `table_[i]` and also `paste("table", i, sep = "_")`, but nothing seems to work. This is what I have now.

```
for (i in 2010:2016) {
df %>%
  filter(df$year == i)  ->  table_i}
```

I would like to have 7 tables called `table_2010`, `table_2011`, .., `table_2016`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add a tag for what language this is in? That will help people who know the language to see your question more quickly.

Comment: Is this R?  If so, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679193/how-to-name-variables-on-the-fly) has some excellent advice on your situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to name variables on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679193/how-to-name-variables-on-the-fly)